# How to extract text and pictures from an image file?

Tags: image-processing, image

Let us consider the following image file.

[image]

Is there a way to use Mathematica in order to "read-scan" the image file and then obtain three new images, one containing the computer text, one containing the hand-written text, and one containing the drawing (ship)?

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this one example, a start might be to extract the different colour layers.

```
masks = (ColorReplace[#, {Red -> Black, _ -> White}, .2] &) /@ (ImageRecolor[
     i, {# -> Red}] & /@ Rest[DominantColors[i]])
```

This gives us back two images:

[image]

and then we can use these as masks on the original image:

```
ImageAdd[#, i] & /@ masks
```

[image]

It may be possible to use `ImageBoundingBoxes` or (more likely) another neural network based approach to separate the text and the boat - `ImageBoundingBoxes` is apparently not trained on pictures of text.

<sup>(The "test text" example makes me think this is one of hundreds of images, and it seems unlikely that you will find a blanket solution for this class of problem that doesn't require a fair bit of hand-tweaking per image.)</sup>

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to retain the blue color of the hand-written text and the boat?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Yes, using those as masks - I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Let's use the color scheme:

```
colors = DominantColors[img];
detects = ColorDetect[img, #] & /@ Rest[colors];
Binarize /@ detects
```

[image]