# Semantic Image Segment of grayscale Text Image

Tags: image-processing, ocr

[How to extract text and pictures from an image file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/254000/6648)

[image]

Consider this grayscale image, how to segment the handwriting part without using Color Information。

Q0:BoundingBox of different patterns:
text,  "handwriting-style" fonts, graph without other pattern's content,

ie. Semantic Segment.

like the result in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/257719/6648).

[image]

Q1：Use grayscale image.
Q2：Use binarized image. [Harder]

### Result is something like the following image,
[image]

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for bounding boxes of the two separate texts, or the text itself? Also, what about the boat? Generating training data for the simplest version of this problem doesn't seem too hard, there are plenty of "handwriting-style" fonts out there and generating a bunch of images with overlapping texts and their bounding boxes seems OK...

Comment: @CarlLange  Yes, see my edit, Semantic Image Segment，the text image itself and the boat graph itself.